# Sql loader date format not recognized

Tags: sql, database, oracle, controls, loader

I have in my application a sql loader , which inserts some dates  and other data 
in the database . In simplified version, the following :

```
INTO TABLE DONNEES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(ID NUMBER
,DAT_FR date "YYYY/MM/DD"
,DAT date "to_date('01'||to_char(:DAT_FR,'MMYYYY'),'DDMMYYYY')"
```

DAT_FR is correct, but I have an error for DAT. For exemple, if DAT_FR equals 2016/07/14, I want DAT "equals" in my database 2016/07/01 (first day of the month).

The error is : "ORA-01821: date format not recognized"

Could you help me ?

Sample input :

```
1;2016/05/31
2;2016/06/14
```

Comment: Can you show us sample input?

Comment: I add sample input in my post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INTO TABLE DONNEES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
    ID NUMBER,
    DAT_FR date "TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:DAT_FR, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM') || '/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD'"
)
```